# FolderBrowserDialog behavior in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows

I'm using a [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) in my application. 
If I try to create a 'New Folder' within the `FolderBrowserDialog` and immediately after I try to rename the 'New Folder' and hit OK (not Enter) the [SelectedPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.selectedpath(VS.71).aspx) property has the 'New Folder' in it's path and not the name that I entered on rename.

Is this a Win7 bug?

Comment: Why does this belong on superuser? It's certainly programming related.

Comment: I thought they meant the Windows Folder Browser Dialog, I'll edit it back.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior isn't new to Windows 7 - it's been this way at least as early as Windows XP, possibly earlier (I don't have access to anything earlier to test).

**Update**: How to reproduce on XP

Using Firefox 3.06, Select `Tools|Options` to bring up the options dialog.

Select the `Main` tab, and within the `Downloads` section, select `Save Files to`, then press `Browse` to bring up the Folder selection dialog.

Select `Desktop` as your folder. Press `New Folder`, type any folder name, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Result: The folder name at the bottom of the dialog reads "New Folder", yet your actual selection has the name you gave.

Answer (score -1):

Same on all Windows I think. It's always seemed a little crap, but there you go.

Comment: the problem is that I cannot reproduce it on Windows XP

Comment: See Bevan's answer above for what I meant. The folder name reads "New Folder", however, I am not sure if that name gets carried through as the actual path or not... Whether or not this is the case it still smells buggy to me. Downvote? Surely not.